# drupal 7, no toolbar, strange code

Tags: drupal-7, toolbar

I am new to Drupal. After reading about it and watching some tutorials, I tried to install Drupal 7 to see it for myself. But now it is installed, I see no admin toolbar on top of the page. On the place where the toolbar should be I get the following code:
$S$DWqdyauf.rdiK9FyIjcO5oZuwyz2HaRQiTO2Ot/5o4YIN8fxcH3u

In the middle of the page it does say 'add more content', so I guess I do have an admin account.

I tried to change the rights via PHPadmin, but sometimes I ended up having no access to the page at all anymore.
When I refresh the page I get a different code. 
It happens in both Chrome and Explore.

What can I do to see a toolbar?

Thank you for your time.
Mariska.

Comment: A picture would be very helpful here Mariska.

Comment: I cannot post an image on this website, but I did on this one https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129014/drupal-7-no-toolbar-strange-code

Comment: Looks like a file is corrupt or some has type a random string. That could be in any template file or in a random JS. I see you are running Drupal in localhost, it would have been very helpful to inspect it live with the chrome inspector or firebug inspector to have a better idea of the surrounding HTML structures.

Comment: I deleted drupal and tried again following another tutorial and now I do see the toolbar. I also had both xampp and wampp installed. I deleted xampp, maybe there was a conflict? However, my problem is solved. Thanks for commending.